# Как пустить несколько лучей из одного объекта в unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я только начал изучать Юнити и всего функционала пока не знаю. У меня есть объект, представляющий собой кролика, который передвигается в хаотичном направлении. При вызове функции поиска еды (FindFood) нужно чтобы кролик искал еду. Я пытаюсь реализовать это путем столкновения лучей с объектом еды. Вопрос заключается в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы кролик испускал несколько лучей, которые будут составлять угол его обзора. Или же есть какая-то альтернатива поиска пищи?
Вот мой код:

```
bool FindFood()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.right);
        Ray ray1 = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        Ray ray2 = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.right);
        Ray ray3 = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 10, out hit, 100) || Physics.SphereCast(ray1, 10, out hit, 100) || Physics.SphereCast(ray2, 10, out hit, 100) || Physics.SphereCast(ray3, 10, out hit, 100))
        {
                
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<FoodAi>())
            {
                Food = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<FoodAi>(); 
                targetFood = hit.point;
                flag = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        return false;
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не нужны лучи вовсе.

Алгоритм следующий:

- Каждому обьекту еды назначаешь тег "Dish"
- делаешь Physics.OverlapSphere вокруг кролика и проверяешь все обьекты которые на тебя вернулись в hitColliders на этот тег.

И вот, собственно, ты получаешь список всех обьектов жрачки в некоем заданном тобой радиусе вокруг кролика.